# Get contacts with mobile number

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use this tutorial http://austinknight.net/ionic-framwork-import-phone-contacts/ and so my code is :

```
    function onSuccess(contacts) {

        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            var contact = contacts[i];
            $scope.phoneContacts.push(contact);
        }
        $ionicLoading.hide();

    };
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert(contactError);
    };
    var options = {};
    options.multiple = true;
    $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

In this code, all contacts will push to `$scope.phoneContacts`, I need just contacts with mobile phone number, I checked the `contact` variable in `console.log` and I found the numbers stores in `phoneNumbers` property, but this property is an array and in this array we have `type` property which said this number is mobile or no,

this is the sample record:

```
[Log] Object (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
$$hashKey: "object:52"
addresses: Array[1]
birthday: 254145600000
categories: null
displayName: null
emails: Array[2]
id: 1
ims: null
name: Object
nickname: null
note: null
organizations: Array[1]
phoneNumbers: Array[2]
     0: Object
          id: 0
          pref: false
          type: "mobile"
          value: "(555) 564-8583"
          __proto__: Object
     1: Object
     length: 2
     __proto__: Array[0]
photos: null
rawId: null
urls: null
__proto__: Object
```

Because `phoneNumbers` is an array, I don't know how can I found contacts with `type=mobile` .

Answer (score 0):

Verify if each contact has a mobile number before adding to your scope var.

```
function contactHasMobileNumber(contact) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contact.phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
        var phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[i];
        if (phoneNumber.type == "mobile") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then update your existing function to check for it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var contact = contacts[i];
    if (contactHasMobileNumber(contact)) {
        $scope.phoneContacts.push(contact);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately No, this code just returned 3 contacts !! from about 400 contacts with mobile phone number

Comment: Also I am getting same problem , are you getting solution

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your code in following way :

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        var contact = contacts[i];
        if(contact.phoneNumbers != null)
          $scope.phoneContacts.push(contact);
    }
    $ionicLoading.hide();

};
function onError(contactError) {
    alert(contactError);
};
var options = {};
options.multiple = true;
$cordovaContacts.find(options).then(onSuccess, onError);
```